# Why am I getting this error when trying to unzip this 7z file using python?

Tags: python

I am using this code to unzip this 7z file stored in my desktop, but whenever I attempt to do this i get an error that states

```
Bad7zFile("invalid header data")
py7zr.exceptions.Bad7zFile: invalid header data

with py7zr.SevenZipFile(r"C:\Users\n1.lall\Desktop\folderofzipfiles\filetoextract.7z.001", mode='r') as z:
    z.extractall()
```

Comment: The `.001` file extension/suffix suggests this zip archive has multiple files. Do you have multiple files? I'm guessing if one is missing it might throw an error like this.

Comment: Does it work if the zip extension if `.7z` and not `.001`?

Comment: See the py7zr documentation [here](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#extraction-from-multi-volume-archive) about multi-volume archives.